# Use native record save to fire LWC logic

Tags: lightning-web-components, page-layout, lightning-record-page

I'm developing a custom UI using an LWC that will be displayed on a lightning record page. It allows the user to answer a few questions, determines whether a handful of fields are required based on the input, and then allows the user to set values for the required fields.

Is it possible to link LWC logic to the lightning page record save button so that when the native save button is clicked, I can also run some LWC logic to update the fields that are set on the LWC? Alternatively, is it possible to trigger the native lightning record save action from the LWC code so that I can add a custom Save button that also triggers the native save?

Comment: I can imagine a solution using Push Topics and `lightning/empApi` that would allow your LWC to get notified when a record is updated server-side.  Of course, it would be better if you could subscribe to something client-side -- your LWC would be able to jump into action much quicker.  I find myself wishing that the native Save button published something to Lightning Message Service that you could subscribe to.  But I don't know of any such functionality.  Failing that option, are you interested in hearing more about the server-side option I initially mentioned?